# nodejs run async function one after another

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await

I'm new to JS/nodejs, so please pardon me if I can't ask to-the-point question.

So basically, if I have two async functions,

```
async function init() {...}
async function main() {...}
```

How can I make sure to call main() after init() has finished its async requests?

Specifically, I want to make use of the module
https://www.npmjs.com/package/hot-import

whereas on its page, there is a sample code:

```
async function main() {
  const MODULE_CODE_42 = 'module.exports = () => 42'
  const MODULE_CODE_17 = 'module.exports.default = () => 17'

  const MODULE_FILE = path.join(__dirname, 't.js')

  fs.writeFileSync(MODULE_FILE, MODULE_CODE_42)
  const hotMod = await hotImport(MODULE_FILE)
  . . .
```

The sample code works as it is, but when I put that into a event call back function, things start to break -- It works for the first event trigger but not the second.

I think the problem is not the constant `hotMod`, but the **await** hotImport in **async** function that is causing the problem. Thus I'm trying to define `hotMod` as a global variable and do `hotMod = await hotImport(MODULE_FILE)` in a `async init()` function *before* `main()` is called. But so far I've not been able to, as I'm quite new to JS/nodejs.

Please help. Thx.

Comment: No, I don't think making a global promise variable will help anything. You're not calling `main` multiple times anyway, right? Please tell us more about what exactly breaks apart when you put something into an event handler, and post a [mcve] with the not working code.

Comment: @Bergi, true, I totally agree. However, the program that I'm writing is for https://github.com/Chatie/wechaty, I can give a  minimal example for that, but it depends on a monster amount of modules, and I don't know nodejs good enough to give another event triggering example in a  minimal way. I do feel that making a global promise variable will not help  anything though. This is my dilemma.

Comment: You need to show us the relevant code for the circumstance that doesn't work, describe what you wanted to happen and describe what you observed that was different than that.  Right now, it looks like you're just showing us a piece.  And, you probably need to show the code for `hotImport()` because if it isn't returning a promise that is linked to when it's done, then the `await` won't do what you want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

using aysnc await

```
async function myFlow(){
.....
await init();
main();
....
}
```

In above code main() will be called only when init is resolved().
I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks a lot Varun for thinking logically and looking _through_ what I'm _trying_ to ask and give the to-the-point answer that hits the nail right on its head!!! BINGO! Splendid ***simple*** answer for a simple question like my OP. Thanks!

Comment: This really helped me. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

async function return promises. So you should be able to call one after the other with `then()`

```
init()
.then(() => main())
```

If `init` returns something (for example `hotMod`), you can pick it up as a parameter to then's callback.

```
init()
.then((init_return) => {
   // do something with init_return
   return  main()
})
```

Comment: Even simpler: `init.then(main)`

Comment: No doubt, @Bergi -- just trying to make the explicit connection in case there's a return value from `init()`

Answer (score 2):

To run them synchronously, just do:

```
await init()
await main()
```