# nodejs to run jobs defined in array one after another

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, async-await

Following up on [nodejs run async function one after another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53898917/)

I found that my jobs defined in array are all run at once:

```js
const { promisify } = require('util')
const wait = promisify(setTimeout)

async function longjob(ms) {
  await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms));
}

const longjobs = [ 100, 200, 120 ]

async function myFlow(){
  longjobs.forEach( async (j) => {
    await longjob(j)
    console.log(`done ${j}`)
    await wait(500)
    console.log(`done wait ${j}`)
  })
}
                  
myFlow()
```

```
$ node jobs_in_array.js 
done 100
done 120
done 200
done wait 100
done wait 120
done wait 200
```

But I want to to run those jobs defined in array one after another.
I must have missing something very simple. please help.

Comment: async does not work the way you expect it to. you need to work with explicit promises

Comment: yeah I am writing a sample I think will work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though you're passing an `async` callback into `.forEach()`, it doesn't wait for its execution. So you end up calling 3 asynchronous functions one after the other but there is nothing that indicates that the script should wait for each of them to execute.

What you can do instead is use `for ... of` loop:

```
async function myFlow(){
  for (const j of longjobs) {
    await longjob(j)
    console.log(`done ${j}`)
    await wait(500)
    console.log(`done wait ${j}`)
  }
}
```